# Jline with completion candidates having space giving unexpected output

Tags: java, jline, jline3

I am using Jline 3.21.0 and trying to run a simple test with reference from
https://github.com/jline/jline3/blob/master/reader/src/test/java/org/jline/reader/completer/StringsCompleterTest.java

Below is one of the modified testcase with candidates having spaces in them. After giving input as **"foo b"** without quote and pressing tab am expecting output to be **"foo bar"**. But I get output as **"foo foo bar"**.

Is this expected behavior ? How can I fix it ? Thanks in advance.

```
        DefaultParser dp = (DefaultParser) reader.getParser();
        dp.setEscapeChars(new char[]{});
        reader.setVariable(LineReader.ERRORS, 0);
        reader.setParser(dp);
        reader.setCompleter(new StringsCompleter("foo bar", "foo foo", "foo shoo"));

        assertBuffer("foo bar ", new TestBuffer("foo b").tab()); // fails actual is "foo foo bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Here is the complete response
https://github.com/jline/jline3/issues/792